# RangeError: Invalid WebSocket frame: RSV2 and RSV3 must be clear

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, crash

I encountered this error on the nodejs application using socket io. This error is difficult to reproduce because it only happens on production environment. The server has been running for several hours, everything was fine and suddenly the error appeared and caused the server crash. I have tried searching on google, on github, on stackoverflow but have not found any solution to this problem. Could someone help me? Thank you very much.

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let http = require('http').Server(app, {
    transports: ['websocket']
});
let io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    //do something
});
```

Comment: This question is old, but I just found this while searching for the same issue. Also in production, but using the `ws` npm library.